# Why using Spaces in Names of Files and Directory in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

When I use other sketch files, I always see that the namings of files and directories have spaces in it. For me it does not make sense, because in coding file and directory names with spaces cause trouble. It starts when you use a terminal - you can not open a directory which includes spaces easily, there is always some more writing because the directory or file you want to open needs to start with " and ends with ".

what is the actual added value here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with graphic design. You can get an answer here though: https://superuser.com/questions/29111/what-technical-reasons-exist-for-not-using-space-characters-in-file-names

Comment: What is it then? it is a question regarding sketch

Comment: thanks for the link, could not find anything like that. so not using spaces is definitely a better option ;)

Comment: Well, it's a question regarding file systems, operating systems, and naming structures. It's a question about computer architecture and operations, not graphic design.The question has next to nothing to do with Sketch specifically. -- Imagine.... I drink coffee while working at my graphic design job... that does *not* make questions about brewing coffee on topic.

Comment: example: you go in your sketch file, which is a design tool, and change the name of an artboard. Isn't it then a graphic design question? :) and I do not want to know it from coders, here i know it. I want to know it from graphic designers, if there is any sense to use spaces in names.

Comment: Graphic designers don't really care whether or not there are spaces. If anything, spaces are preferred for, as @Tetsujin pointed out, human legibility.

Comment: While there is some relevance to graphic design (legibility), this seems to me more closely related to file management and reads more like a rant than a question. I'll consider reopening if anyone else has anything they'd like to add.

Comment: as I am a graphic designer too, I care :P that is what I meant. Maybe you all guys don't need to think of it, but I need to, so I ask others, what are their intentions. and I do not see human legibility is better with spaces, it is the same with underscores! But thank you all, next time I will post it somewhere else, when it is a question regarding file management to graphic designers :)

Answer (score 3):

Human legibility.

Operating systems have been quite capable of handling spaces since about the mid 90's… even if the coders & Terminal hackers have to work harder, to the user they're 'invisible helpers'

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102960/discussion-on-answer-by-tetsujin-why-using-spaces-in-names-of-files-and-director).